# Como pegar um elemento especifico entre varios da mesma classe via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, classes

Galera, provavelmente isso é algo extremamente simples mas estou penando pra resolver:

Supondo um codigo

```
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto1">
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto2">
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto3">
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto4">
```

Há uma forma de pegar o input com o texto3 via jquery? Com javascript puro eu usaria

`var texto = document.getElementsByClassname("campos")[2].value`

mas `$(".campo")[2].val()` não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz assim:

```js
let el = $('[value="texto3"]');

console.log(el.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto1">
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto2">
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto3">
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto4">
```

Ou se quiser pegar sempre o 3º elemento:

```js
let el = $('.campos').get(2);

console.log(el.value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto1">
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto2">
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto3">
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto4">
```

Comment: Gostei do .get(). Assim posso usar um for pra percorrer todos os campos em busca de um valor especifico. Acabei usando document.getElementsByClassName pois precisava botar pra funcionar com urgencia. Assim que der vou alterar pra deixar padronizado c/ JQuery. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o seletor [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), exemplo:

```js
console.log($('.campos:eq(2)').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto1">
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto2">
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto3">
<input type = "text" class = "campos" value = "texto4">
```

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode pegar pelo `id` do campo, ai pegará um campo específico, mesmo eles pertencendo à mesma classe CSS. Para chamar pelo id, basta colocar o `#` antes do id do campo desejado:

```js
console.log($('#text2').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<input type = "text" id= "text1" class = "campos" value = "texto1">
<input type = "text" id= "text2" class = "campos" value = "texto2">
<input type = "text" id= "text3" class = "campos" value = "texto3">
<input type = "text" id= "text4" class = "campos" value = "texto4">
```